# how to read field value Cakephp 2 / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

i m in elements/navigation.ctp , in the navbar i put a condition if :

```html
<li class="dropdown"> 
                                         
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-bell">
    <?php 
    //$location_status=$this->data['Location']['status'];
    //$location= $this->Location->find("status = '$location_status'");
    //$this->Session->write('Location', $location['Location']);
    //$this->loadModel("Location");
    if($this->Location->read('Location.status')!==0):
        echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" style="color:red;">
    </span>';
     ?>
    
    <?php endif;?>
    </i>
    <b class="caret">
    </b>
    </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu alert-dropdown">
        <li>
           <a href="#"><span class="label label-danger">Notificaion</span></a>
        </li>

        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">View All</a>
        </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

i went when the field status in Location table is == 0 it displays a notification icon, and when it is 1 it shows nothing, but the problem i think that i have put the false code

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the correct way to access a model within an element. You could try sending the `Location.status` as a parameter to your element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have the solution , i just import model in my view and this is the code :

```html
App::import('Model', 'Location');
$this->Location = new Location();

       if ($this->Location->field('status')=='0'):
           

echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" style="color:red;">
    </span>';
```